# prevent showing two scrollbars when modal opens

Tags: html, css

In my page, I have a modal that opens when a button is clicked. But it looks wonky because two scrollbars show up:

[image]

The css I used: https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa?editors=1100

I want it to have only the scrollbar for the modal when the modal is open and switch back to the parent scrollbar when closed. I tried doing it with `overflow-y: hidden`, but that disables scrolling instead.

What am I missing here?

Comment: @Keara ah but I don't want to hide the scrollbar

Comment: Oh, my bad. I think I see what you're getting at now :)

Answer (score 0):

Its not showing me two scrollbars when I see your project on Codepen

[image: I think there is a problem with your Browser]

I think there is a problem with your Browser

Comment: I dont think there's something wrong with my browser. But the way my page loads is that on first load, there's already lots of content, thus showing the scrollbar on the parent html. Then when I click on the modal, it has its content and scrollbar, then it shows two scrollbars instead of just the modal